# Sum of nil left ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Let $I,J$ be left ideals in a ring $A$ such that $\forall x\in I \ \ \forall y \in J$ we have that  $x,y$ are nilpotent. Is then true that every element of $I+J$ is nilpotent? Now, if the ideals are bilateral, expanding $(x+y)^{n_0}$ and "playing" a little bit with the exponent $n_0$ we've proved that the answer is: yes. But I think a different approach is needed with the hypothesis that $I,J$ are left ideals. Any suggestion?

Comment: left/right/two-sided Ideals whose elements are all nilpotent are called *nil*. A left/right/twosided ideal $I$ is called *nilpotent* if there is an $n$ such that $I^n=\{0\}$. Asking whether or not the sum of two nil one-sided ideals is again nil is a longstanding open question called the [Koethe conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6the_conjecture)